# Is there any swift function call right before user turns off his internet?

Tags: ios, swift, events

Is there any event right before user turns off his internet? Like we have applicationWillTerminate.I have to call an API to update sever , internet is going off.

Comment: The network connection can go away at any time for any number of reasons. The user activating airplane mode or similar is probably one of the least likely reasons. You can perhaps use path monitor as per the answer below to record the time the connection went away and then update your server when the connection comes back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. You can't detect the connection to the Internet is going until it has gone. If you think about it, the usual reasons for losing the Internet connection are things like routers going down or moving out of cellphone coverage. There's no way you can predict that.

The best you can do is detect that the network has gone down and try to mitigate the effects e.g. if you were trying to send something to a server, persist the data locally and resend it when the connection comes back. If you want the server to know it has lost contact with the device, you can ping it regularly, say every minute and if it doesn't hear from your device after a minute, it will know you have lost your connection.

Comment: As I am working on a project where we monitors guards. By considering your answer I think I can save locally the reason behind connection loss **" 1: User turned off his data" or " 2: signal lost"** . Then update server reason behind connection lost when connection comes back.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NWPathMonitor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwpathmonitor) like this - requires `iOS 12`

```
import Network

let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
monitor.start(queue: DispatchQueue(label: "NetworkMonitor"))
monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { (path) in
    if path.status == .satisfied {
        print("Connected")
    } else {
        print("Not Connected")
    }
}
```

This allows more granular control as well `.cellular`, `.wifi` & `.wiredEthernet` etc. -

```
let cellMonitor = NWPathMonitor(requiredInterfaceType: .cellular)
```

---

If you still support `iOS 11`, you can use a 3rd party library like - [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability)